# Selecting Radio Button from database in MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I was going through a tutorial on MVC in which it was being shown how to create radio buttons based on the entries in the Database table. Being new to MVC and Linq I am confused as to what does `m=>m.SelectedCompany` actually do in the following code?

**Table**

```
+-----------+-------------+------------+
| CompnayId | CompanyName | IsSelected |
+-----------+-------------+------------+
|         1 | Accenture   |          0 |
|         2 | CMS         |          1 |
|         3 | Microsoft   |          0 |
+-----------+-------------+------------+
```

**MODEL:**

```
public class CompanyC
{
    public string SelectedCompany { get; set; }
    public List<Company>  Companies
    {
        get
        {
            testDbContext db = new testDbContext();
            return db.Companies1.ToList();
        }
    }

}
```

**CONTROLLER:**

```
public class CompanyController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Company/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        CompanyC company = new CompanyC();
        return View(company);
    }

}
```

**VIEW:**

```
@model MvcKudvenkat1.Models.CompanyC

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    foreach (var company in Model.Companies)
    {
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(m=>m.SelectedCompany,company.CompnayId) @company.CompanyName
    }
    <br />

}
```

I tried looking into MSDN to understand the syntax of RadioButtonFor , but I have no clue what `RadioButtonFor<TModel, TProperty> Method (HtmlHelper<TModel>, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>>, Object)` this means?

Basically My question is .. 
What are the different arguments does RadioButtonFor accepts and what does `m=>m.SelectedCompany` do in the above code?

Comment: `m => m.SelectedCompany` means your radio button group is binding to property `SelectedCompany` and the 2nd parameter sets the `value` of the button (when you submit, the value of `SelectedCompany` in your model will be the value of the selected button).

Comment: m=>m.SelectedCompany creates the radio button with that name , and its value in the next overload

Comment: Side note: Do not put code that accesses your database in a model. You have made your app impossible to unit test.

Comment: @StephenMuecke @REDEVI_   Forgive  me if my question seems stupid but why cant i replace `m=>m.SelectedCompany` with `company.IsSelected` ?

Comment: Your model does not have a property named `IsSelected` (only the `Company` model has one - but that would make no sense)

Comment: @StephenMuecke I think I am still not clear on how  `@Html.RadioButtonFor` works. : (

Comment: Not sure what it is that you trying to do. If you wanting to edit each `Company` and set the `IsSelected` property, then the model in the view needs to be `@model List<Company>` and then you use a checkbox for the `IsSelected` property

Comment: @StephenMuecke As you can see in the table. There are three rows. So view should automatically generate 3 radio buttons on the fly one for each company. The last column in table is bits. So by default CMS must be selected when view loads.

Comment: Then you set the value of `SelectedCompany` to `2` in the controller before you pass the model to the view (and the 2nd radio button will be selected) - but since the `value` attributes are based on an `int` property, then the property should be `public int SelectedCompany { get; set; }` (not `string`)

Comment: @StephenMuecke A bit clearer .. thanks